# Installing windows update after patch Tuesday

Tags: windows, puppet

The Saturday after each patch Tuesday (which is the second Tuesday of the month), I want to install updates via Puppet. I made a scheduled task for this, itself managed via a `scheduled_task` resource from the puppetlabs/scheduled_task module.  I am using this trigger for that task:

```
    $trigger = {
      schedule         => monthly,
      start_time       => '13:15',
      which_occurrence => second,
      day_of_week      => [sat],
      minutes_interval => '80',
      minutes_duration => '560',
    }
```

.  However, on months like this one, where the second Tuesday comes AFTER the second Saturday, this trigger launches the task on the wrong day. How can I make the task fire on the first Saturday following the second Tuesday of each month?

It might be possible to count the days after patch Tuesday, but this would require Puppet to be able to get the date of every second Tuesday of the month (which it can't AFAIK).

Comment: Core Puppet has no built in facility going by the name "scheduled task".  Are perhaps talking about using the `puppetlabs/scheduled_task` module?

Comment: Yes, this is the module that I am using. However, it does not seem to play well with counting from a specific day (so say, counting 4 days from the second Tuesday).

Answer (score 0):

The puppetlabs/task_scheduler module manages tasks that are to be run via Windows' built-in Task Scheduler service.  Puppet does not itself run the tasks; it just registers them with the system service and manages their properties.  This is a problem for you, because as far as I can determine, the Windows task scheduler does not support the type of scheduling you're looking for.  Of course, puppetlabs/scheduled_task cannot provide for something that the underlying OS does not support.

Your alternatives include, but are not necessarily limited to:

- Choose a different schedule for your task.  For example, schedule the task for the third Saturday of the month, which will always follow the second Tuesday.
- Use an `Exec` to perform the update, with a combination of conditional logic and a Puppet schedule for controlling the date and frequency of application.

It is true that the latter requires Puppet to perform some date computations.  Puppet can do that, but you would probably need to write a custom function (in Ruby) for that purpose.  Custom functions are accessible during catalog building, and they can use substantially all the capabilities of Ruby.